# codeigniter pagination link url not correct

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

my setting for codeigniter pagination was this:

```
$this->load->library("pagination");
$config = array();
$config['base_url']     =  site_url('page/stok');
$config['total_rows']   = $this->posting_model->count_all_stok();
$config['per_page'] = 10;
$config['uri_segment']  = 3;
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;

$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

but how come my page url become like this if I hover to page 2:

```
http://localhost:8080/pmm/page/stok/10
```

what do I wronged here?

Comment: I might assume that it's typical for calling `site_url()` on `localhost`. Does `http://localhost:8080/pmm/page/stok/10` works or you getting errors?

Comment: it works, but I need it to `http://localhost:8080/pmm/page/stok/2`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pagination do not correct display page numbers Codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046149/pagination-do-not-correct-display-page-numbers-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

This is how `site_url()` works if you did not set `base_url` in **config/config.php**. Try to specify it correctly: `$config['base_url'] = '//yoursite.com/';`.

Answer (score 0):

add this line to your controller before load pagination library

```
$config['uri_segment'] = 3; //or try 4
```